# Trying to Post some info to DRF API but being met with 403 forbidden error using Python Requests

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am trying to GET access to my DRF API and I am trying to authenticate against my API but I cannot post my username/password (Data) as I get a 403 HTTP Error before I was getting a Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) error then I changed my view to a DRF Class based view now I am stuck on this error unable to POST anything to my API

REQUESTS (Outside the Django Project)

```
payload = {'username': 'user', 'password': '****'}

r = requests.get('http://website/api/login/', data=payload)
```

urls

```
app_name = 'api'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_to_api.as_view(), name = "login_to_api"),
```

Views

```
class CustomerListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

class CustomerRetrieveAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

class login_to_api(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            (logic)
```

HTML

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" action="{% url 'api:login_to_api' %}" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td><label >Username</label></td>
                    <td><input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label >Password</label></td>
                    <td><input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
            {%csrf_token%}
            </table>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
```

settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )#,'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ( 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', )
}



REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are trying to use a session based auth while you only configured the basic authentication - which requires the login/passwd to be provided for each request

Comment: Configuring Session Auth makes no difference still get the same issue

Comment: the issue is different though the http result is the same. If you go for session auth, you'll have to provide CSRF token for POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE operations. Django's documentation explains about it. If you go with BasicAuth, JPG already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way I fixed it is by removing is_authenticated from the settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

and in the views put `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)` in each of the classed based views other than in the login view so then I was able to post my credentials to the view to login and in my requests logic created a session then went to the login view then requested any other views needed

Answer (score 2):

You are using the python's requests module in the wrong way.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username='user', password='****')
api_url = 'http://website/api/some/list/api/'

r = requests.get(url=api_url, auth=auth)
```

Reference: [**basic Authentication Using `requests`**](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't solve the issue as I got a custom authentication and I need to post the parameters also I get a 403 on the get request

Comment: custom authentication? Where? I can't find that in your provided code snippet.

Comment: It's where it says (logic) I just didn't add it as I thought it isn't relevant to the problem as the issue is passing parameters to the method 
Apologies for this

Comment: This was definitely the right answer for me without any token auth setup. Thanks!